# Instafeed tutorial, pictures are not loading

Tags: django, instagram

I am trying to implement the instafeed tutorial to just show some instagram pictures.

I am working on PyCharm using Django.

Here is my folder hierarchy:
    /test_project/js/instafeed.min.js

I have a suspicion that I am not referencing the 'src' correctly. I had 'Cannot resolve directory' warnings before, but I got them to disappear by playing around with the Source preferences.

Here's the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/instafeed.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'b8dacdbf587f41798d8dfb03e3f7a29',
        useHTTP: true
    });
    feed.run();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="instafeed">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I used the 'useHTTP:true' because I saw on another answer that this needs to be set to true to work on a local machine. I've looked at how the code was used in other tutorials and implementations, but I don't see how my code is any different.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this source in your static assets folder? if so its just `{% static '/js/instafeed.min.js' %}`

Answer (score 0):

Instafeed needs jQuery (the documentation says that you don't need, but i got some errors without it), so make sure you have both libs loaded correctly.

Try with this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.lukej.me/instafeed.js/1.2.0/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```